# Can you have multiple getenv in C++ if statement?

Tags: c++

For example this works

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
 
int main()
{
    if(const char* env_p = std::getenv("PATH"))
        std::cout << "Your PATH is: " << env_p << '\n';
}
```

but this doesn't

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cstdlib>
  
    int main()
{
    if((const char* env_p = std::getenv("PATH")) && (const char* env_p = std::getenv("PATH")))
        std::cout << "Your PATH is: " << env_p << '\n';
        std::cout << "Your PATH is: " << env_p << '\n';
}
```

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:6:9: error: expected primary-expression before 'const'
    6 |     if((const char* env_p = std::getenv("PATH")) && (const char* env_p = std::getenv("PATH")))
      |         ^~~~~
main.cpp:6:9: error: expected ')' before 'const'
    6 |     if((const char* env_p = std::getenv("PATH")) && (const char* env_p = std::getenv("PATH")))
      |        ~^~~~~
```

How do you check all env parameter exist?

I can do nested if, but that seems ugly

Comment: Can you think of different ways to declare variables in a C++ function?

Comment: is it possible to check if 2 different env exist at the same time in the same if statement without creating variable outside the if statement?

Comment: Of course, but this has nothing to do with declaring variables. See your C++ textbook for more information. What is the topic of the chapter in your C++ textbook, where this programming assignment is from?

Comment: If anyone thinks the first part doesn't work, please note that the first part is legal as of C++17 (see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if)) (which surprised me too).

Answer (score 3):

In C++17 you can do this:

```
if(char const *env1_p = std::getenv("PATH1"), *env2_p = std::getenv("PATH2"); env1_p && env2_p)
{
   std::cout << "Your PATH is: " << env1_p << '\n';
   std::cout << "Your PATH is: " << env2_p << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't declare multiple variables in an `if` statement's condition using the `&&` operator like that.

You can, however, declare both variables before the condition, like this:

```
const char* env_p1;
const char* env_p2;
if((env_p1 = std::getenv("VAR1")) && (env_p2 = std::getenv("VAR2"))) {
        std::cout << "Your VAR1 is: " << env_p1 << '\n';
        std::cout << "Your VAR2 is: " << env_p2 << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with having multiple calls to a function.

The problem is declaring multiple variables. You can't declare multiple variables in an [initializer `if` statement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if)'s condition.

```
if (bool b = true) { ... } // fine
if (bool b = true && bool f = false) { ... } // error
```

If you have something more complicated than `if (type var = expr)` then you should not cram the variable declarations into the condition. Use:

```
const char* env_p1 = std::getenv("PATH1"));
const char* env_p2 = std::getenv("PATH2"));

if (evp_p1 && evp_p2) {

}
```